# "In his ear" - preposition phrase or adverbial phrase?

Tags: prepositional-phrases, adverbial-phrases

> In his ear, he whispers gaily.

Is *"in his ear"* a prepositional or an adverbial phrase?

Please explain your choice and give some reasons for your answer. Thanks!

Comment: Try including the sentence that caused you confusion. A phrase by itself, not in a sentence, can be prepositional, adverbial, or even other things. In English grammar, nearly everything depends strongly on context.

Comment: Didn't you just ask this same question earlier today?  http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/78549/ok-i-am-totally-flustered-by-the-following

Comment: @stangdon I think this should remain, but the first sentence of the original question should be deleted to split the question.

Comment: Please do not closevote as a duplicate: this question **was** part of an earlier question, but has now been extracted from it and no longer duplicates.

Answer (score 9):

It is both.

The term *preposition phrase* describes the phrase's internal structure: it is constructed with a preposition followed by its object.

The term *adverbial phrase* describes the phrase's external syntactic role: it designates the place where the action was directed and is taken to "modify" the action in the same way as an adverb like *softly* or *angrily* would.

Comment: @Araucaria I agree with your characterization of *adverbial*, but I am dubious about "worth mentioning": OP appears to be under the eye of a traditionalist pedagogue, and it may be indiscreet to proselytize.

Comment: Yes, indeed that was more for your amusement really, if I'm honest. Will delete in a bit.